# How to obtain clipname while shooting?

Tags: workflow, recording, shooting, sdi

Is there any kind of solution to obtain simultaneous the clipname while shooting? prehaps to read hanc and fanc of the SDI signal? I use a sony AX1 4K.

Answer (score 1):

Both RED and Alexa cameras offer this feature, and the Sound Devices PIX 240i [reads it](http://cdn.sounddevices.com/download/tech/Arri%20Alexa%20Interconnection.pdf).  But nowhere on the Internet is there any documentation that your SONY camera offers this feature.  Either SONY doesn't have it, or they greatly need to improve their documentation.